# JFormDesigner generating Java Code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jform-designer

I am using JFormDesigner to develop a Swing application.    However I can't seem to get the package to generate java code.   I tried saving the form and also pressing the "Generate Java Code" button, but it is not working.    Is there some setting that I need to put in place for this to work?

Here is an uppdate.   The generated code file is in my workspace directory, but Eclipse is not refreshing the file.  Also, I note that the icon next to the file name in the navigator view looks different than normal java files.     So really, this seems to be a problem with Eclipse refreshing.  And yes, I've tried manually refreshing.  But it is not doing this. Why would that be?

Thanks,

Elliott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is there.  But is collapsed.   You need to click on the + sign next to the position in the module where the generated code should be and it appears.